# how to change mat-button background color and maintain the color fade

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to change the background color of a angular material `mat-button`, as can be seen in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf75rm-y3hbgt?file=src/app/button-types-example.html) stackblitz example using `background-color: red;` on hover only works for the `mat-raised-button` and when applied to the `mat-button` it removes the fade-in of the background color.

How can I change the background color while still keeping the fade animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if angular material provides a configuration to allow mat-button to have color shade transition. However you can do it easily with one css line:

```css
[mat-button] {
  transition: background 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.8, 0.25, 1),
    box-shadow 280ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
}
```

Here is the stackblitz updated: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xf75rm-77tuxf?file=src/app/button-types-example.scss

Answer (score 1):

The button styles are encapsulated, so you have to use /deep/ selector to change internal styles.

Try this:

```
.link-btn /deep/ .mat-button-focus-overlay {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```